# Product of $x_1,x_2, \ldots, x_n$

Tags: combinatorics

We have $x_1,x_2, \ldots, x_n$ arranged in a row. $n \ge 3$. Every $x_i$ belongs to $\{1,-1\}$. We can choose arbitrarily $3$ consequent numbers and know their product.  Which is the minimum number of questions to know the product of entire row?

When $n$ is a multiple of 3, $n=3k$, the answer is $\frac{n}{3}$. I have no idea how can I solve the problem when $n$ is different than $3k$.

Comment: Have you tried $3k+1,3k+2$?

Comment: yes , I think it will be n when they are arranged in a circle, but I don't know even a solution when they are in a row.

Comment: You asked this very same question yesterday, and then deleted it. Rather than asking it again, you should have undeleted the deleted one.

Comment: yesterday I asked it for a circle.

Answer (score 1):

The task is not always possible: consider $1,-1,1,1$ and $-1,-1,-1,-1$.

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution for n=3k+1 and n=3k+2.
For example when n=13, we can choose the elements at these indexes 1,3,4,6,7,9,10,12,13 ,flip the singes, and therefore the total product will change the sign ,but for every query the answer will maintain the same.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).